# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in StoriesController#edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have correctly defined the params in my controller. It also says `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"stories", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]'`.

However didn't I define it to find the 'id' in the edit method below in my controller? Also, I don't understand why my destroy method isn't working either :/

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
    before_action only: [:destroy, :show, :edit, :update]


def index
    @stories = Story.order('created_at DESC')
end

def new
    @story = current_user.stories.build
end

def create
    @story = current_user.stories.build(story_params)
    if @story.save
        flash[:success] = "Your beautiful story has been added!"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    @story = Story.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    if @story.update.attributes(story_params)
        flash[:success] = "More knowledge, more wisdom"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    if @story.destroy
        flash[:success] = "I think you should have more confidence in your storytelling"
    else
        flash[:error] = "Can't delete this story, sorry"
    end
end

def show
    @stories = Story.all
end

private

def story_params
    params.require(:story).permit(:name, :description)
end



end
```

Index.html.erb:

```
    <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>


    <h1>This is a list of posts</h1>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>User</th>
                <th colspan="3"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <% @stories.each do |story| %>
            <tr>
            <td><%= story.name %></td>
            <td><%= story.description %></td>
            <td><%= story.user.email %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Show', story %></td>
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_story_path(@story) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', story, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %></td>
            <% end %>
            </tr>
            <% end %>

        </tbody>
    </table>

  <%= link_to 'New Story', new_story_path %>
```

Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

resources :stories
devise_for :users
root to: 'stories#index'
end
```

rake routes:

```
  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
                 stories GET    /stories(.:format)             stories#index
                         POST   /stories(.:format)             stories#create
               new_story GET    /stories/new(.:format)         stories#new
              edit_story GET    /stories/:id/edit(.:format)    stories#edit
                   story GET    /stories/:id(.:format)         stories#show
                         PATCH  /stories/:id(.:format)         stories#update
                         PUT    /stories/:id(.:format)         stories#update
                         DELETE /stories/:id(.:format)         stories#destroy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view,

**`<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_story_path(@story) %></td>`**

Should be,

**`<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_story_path(story) %></td>`**

Because, your `loop` is,

**You should be having story variable inside loop because you have taken |story| inside the parameters as  |story|**

**So, you form will be.**

```
<% @stories.each do |story| %>
      <tr>
            <td><%= story.name %></td>
            <td><%= story.description %></td>
            <td><%= story.user.email %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Show', story %></td>
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
                  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_story_path(@story) %></td>
                  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', story_path(story),method: :delete,data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
            <% end %>
      </tr>
<% end %>
```

**Now, the delete link should be like this,**

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', story_path(story),method: :delete,data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

Comment: Thank you. Why is it story and not @story?

Comment: In your for loop, you are looping `story` local variable and not `@story`

Comment: check the answer now, it has some explanation

Comment: Amazing, thanks! I'll mark the answer correct when the timer has run out as I have wait 5 minutes!

Comment: please check the latest answer now, also added the delete link.

Comment: Your very kind!